# ondrop check condition in if condition not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to drop a drag item box2 on checking a condition, after checking the condition if the condition is `true` drop should happen, but condition is not working.
also I'm trying to load another image in the place of drag item after sucessfull drop.
how to achieve it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box").click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'none');
    $(this).css('opacity', '0.0');
  });
});

$(function () {

 $(".box2").draggable({
  revert: "valid",
  drag: function (event, ui) {
   $("").html(");
  }
 });
 
 $(".box").droppable({
  
  var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
  var id2 = ui.droppable.attr("id");

     if(id % id2 === 10) {
                           
  drop: function (event, ui) {
   $(this).css("background-color", "lightgreen")
  },
  out: function (event, ui) {
   $(this).css("background-color", "")
     )
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 30%;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10%;
    background-color: #006600;
}

.box002 {
        float: left;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" id="10">
    <div class="text">8.40</div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="20">
    <div class="text">12.25</div>
</div>

<div class="box2" id="2">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"  draggable="true" id="1" style="width:200px; height:200px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded"/>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't declare conditions in an object. You have to use event handlers.

Comment: also you have problems with brackets (one `)` should probably be `}` although you have to fix what Huelfe has suggested first). And please don't tag your questions with anything that's mentioned *inside* the question, tag what your question is *about*. Best regards